# How can I use ARCore with CameraX?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-jetpack, arcore

I know ARCore using Camera2 by default. I was wondering about how we can use it with CameraX?

Is any way to use ARCore with CameraX?

I just tried shared session ARCore samples, It's using Camera2 API.

Is any approach or extension to use ARCore with CameraX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas! As of today, Google ARCore 1.35 is [still not capable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68682709/is-it-possible-to-use-arcore-with-camerax) of using Android Jetpack's library CameraX, although CameraX is integrated with many MLKit features including barcode scanning, face detection, text recognition, etc.

Comment: Hi, is any possible to create our own extensions, and i saw there is no Public Available Source code for Arcore :(

Comment: I only know about this approach – https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity-arf/getting-started-extensions